# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1142: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, tweepy, python-unicode

I have used tweepy API to extract tweets and have written it into a CSV with "utf-8" encoding. I am individually parsing through each row in the csv to display the tweet onto my HTML front-end. At certain times I get the above mentioned UnicodeDecode error when I run my flask code.

I have looked at several answers related to this on SO, like adding the line "# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-" to my flask code, and fixing it through cmd using the command "chcp 65001". But the error is still thrown once in a while.

Below is the function which reads the tweet from csv:

```
    def tweet1(self):
    with open('HELLOTWITTER.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        d = {}
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            d[row[0]]=row[1:]
            if (i>=10):
                break    
    ks=list(d)
    return (ks[0])
```

Also, someone said that the error is with the "enumerate()". Is that true? Can anyone give me a clue as to where the issue is? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which python version are you using? try it on python3.

Comment: @Kjjassy : I am running it on Python3.6

Comment: could you provide stacktrace for the error and some example of invalid csv file?